# Java Calendar WEEK_OF_YEAR not ISO-8601compliant?

Tags: java, date, iso

The ISO-8601 standard states that

> "The first week of a year is the week that contains the first Thursday
>   of the year (and, hence, always contains 4 January)."

Meaning the first week of the year is not that which contains January the 1st but the first one that contains at leat four days into the new year.

Acording to that Mon, January 11 2016 is on week #2. [Here is a list of week numbers for 2016.](http://www.epochconverter.com/date-and-time/weeknumbers-by-year.php?year=2016)

Ubuntu reflects that in its time widget:

[image]

And the cal command does also:

[image]

Oracle supports it with the "iw" parameter of `TO_CHAR`:

```
> select to_char(to_date('11/01/2016','dd/mm/yyyy'),'iw') weekno from dual;
> WEEKNO
    02
```

But Java says Mon, January 11 2016 is week #3

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
System.out.println(c.getTime());
System.out.println(c.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR));

Output:
Mon Jan 11 09:02:35 VET 2016
3
```

Java thinks the first week of the year is the one that contains January the 1st.

**- Is there a way for Java to use the ISO-8601-copliant week numbering?**

Comment: It's locale specific. Setting the default `Locale` to `Locale.UK` for instance, gives the correct week, 2.

Comment: But that would alter other things beside the week number!

Comment: Yes, see my answer below for a better approach. :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As I noted in my comment, the *default behavior* is locale specific. Some locales will give 3, some will give 2.

Luckily, you can specify the number of days that has to be present in the first week of the year, for a given `Calendar`. As you write above, for ISO 8601, this number is `4`, thus the following code should work:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.setMinimalDaysInFirstWeek(4); // For ISO 8601
System.out.println(c.getTime());
System.out.println(c.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR));
```

This should make the output correct regardless of locale.

Test output:

```
Mon Jan 11 14:54:22 CET 2016
2
```

Answer (score 4):

## tl;dr

```
myZonedDateTime.get( IsoFields.WEEK_OF_WEEK_BASED_YEAR )
```

…and…

```
myZonedDateTime.get( IsoFields.WEEK_BASED_YEAR )
```

## Avoid legacy date-time classes

As the [correct Answer by haraldK](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34723186/642706) explains, the **`Calendar` class’s definition of week varies by locale**. While well-intentioned, this is confusing.

You should be avoiding `Calendar` and related classes such as `Date`. They are now supplanted by the *java.time* classes.

## ISO 8601 week

As for [ISO 8601 week](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date), be clear that means:

- The first day is Monday, running through Sunday.
- Week number one of a week-based year contains the first Thursday of the calendar year.
- A week-based year has either 52 or 53 weeks.
- The first/last few days of a calendar year may appear in the previous/next week-based year.

## *java.time*

The *java.time* classes include limited support for [ISO 8601 standard weeks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date). Call the `get` method on various classes such  as [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) and [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html). Pass the [`TemporalField`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalField.html) implementations found as constants in the [`IsoFields`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/temporal/IsoFields.html) class.

```
int week = myZonedDateTime.get( IsoFields.WEEK_OF_WEEK_BASED_YEAR ) ;
int weekBasedYear = myZonedDateTime.get( IsoFields.WEEK_BASED_YEAR ) ;
```

## *ThreeTen-Extra*

Even better, add the [*ThreeTen-Extra*](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) library to your project to use [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html) class.

```
org.threeten.extra.YearWeek yw = YearWeek.from( myZonedDateTime ) ;
```

## Beware of calendaring software settings

Never assume the definition of a week number. Be sure the source of such a number has the same definition of week as you, such as ISO 8601 definition.

For example, the [*Calendar* app supplied by Apple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calendar_(Apple)) with macOS defaults to a "Gregorian" calendar definition of week. As for what that means, I do not know as I could not find any documentation about their intent/definition. For ISO 8601 weeks, you must [change a setting away from default](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/191445/17907).

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Using a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later, you may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. No need for strings nor java.sql.* classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).